# Is it possible to restore TWRP backup with CWM?

Tags: recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, twrp

Is it possible to restore TWRP backup with CWM?

I have some backups with Team Win Recovery. If I install ClockWorkMod, can I restore them with it?

Comment: I have never tried; but IMHO both use Nandroid to backup, so it *should* be working. I'd do another backup with TWRP just before switching, and then another one with CWM immediately after, to be on the safe side. In case it does *not* work, there are always other helpers to read them, like *Titanium Backup* or *Nandroid Manager*.

Comment: *That's* always a good approach :) If you go that path, we'd be glad if you'd report back. You could answer your own question then – or give us the pointers to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked that myself.

I installed CWM 6.0.1.0 on my Galaxy Tab P5100, then I tried to restore the TWRP backup that I already had, and It didn't work.

Maybe it needs a little more technical work. But with a normal procedure, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It wont Work as the two recoveries are only compatible with their own files.
Xda has a thread on this:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2383065